# SplashScreen появляется не сразу, а через некоторое время - android, java

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

Когда захожу в приложение, то splash screen не отображается вовсе, но если поставить задержку к примеру на 5 секунд, то splash screen появляется примерно через 2 секунды.. Вроде бы он должен появляться сразу после активации приложения, нет?

Есть у меня одно приложение, когда я в него захожу, то там splash screen появляется моментально.

Когда я запускаю свое, то у меня 1-2 секунды белый экран, потом splash screen, а потом уже MainActivity, а иногда вообще splash screen не срабатывает и кидает сразу на MainActivity, но я не хочу делать задержку..
Я пытаюсь понять, почему пару секунд белый экран, а потом только splash screen.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

         startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
         finish();
     }
 }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_splash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Splash"
    android:textSize="70dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Нет, не сразу. Поэтому надо сделать задержку перед запуском главной формы

Comment: @ArtyMorris, но это ведь не правильно. Зачем пользователю ждать несколько секунд? К примеру, есть у меня приложение одно... Когда я его запускаю, то splash screen в нем появляется моментально

Comment: Потому что путь, что вы используете, неправильный. Есть путь через темы, там моментально появляется

Comment: Понял, постараюсь почитать об этом подробнее, спасибо.

Comment: Splash screen как таковой (как он известен на iOS), добавили только в Андроид 12. Все что было до этого -- самопальное и по большей части маркетинг. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, но для него нужен минимум api level 31, а эта api всего у ~1% устройств android.

Comment: Это я ответил скорее на ваш вопрос "Зачем пользователю ждать несколько секунд?". Только для того чтобы посмотреть на ваш splash screen, больше незачем.